# How to round down google map coordinates in my getElementById.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google maps and displaying map coordinates when the map is clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (getcoords) {
document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = (getcoords.latLng.lat() + "," + getcoords.latLng.lng());
                });
```

The coordinates returned have atomic scale precision like so: 55.8907220038651,-2.3968541622161865

How do round these down to five decimal places?

I thought of using toFixed(5), but don't know how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on `.lat()` like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (getcoords) {
    document.getElementById('bar').innerHTML = (getcoords.latLng.lat().toFixed(5) + "," + getcoords.latLng.lng().toFixed(5));
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.